# PayPal Error Message 0

Tags: php, paypal, платежи

*Merchant PayPal* создан и подключен при пополнении. Однако когда пользователь делает вход на свой PayPal, выводится следующая ошибка:

> We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later. If this error occured while making a payment, avoid duplicate payments by checking your Account Overview before resending a payment.
>
> For some browsers, this problem can be resolved by clearing or deleting cookies.
>
> Message 0

В «песочнице» же всё работает.

Код формы:

```html
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="my@gmail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Пополнение счета" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mysite.ru/" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://mysite.ru/" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom"  value="123"/>
<input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Введите сумму" required></input>
<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<button type="submit" value="Перейти к оплате">Перейти к оплате</button>
</form>
```